# How to build wheels for a project that requires other source projects?

Tags: python, python-wheel

I have a project A, that has source ("edit") dependencies on B and C (which happen to be in git submodules). I have a requirements file like this:

```
[requirements.txt]
nose
-e B/src
-e C/src
```

My setup.py lists these packages as deps:

```
[setup.py]
install_requires=[nose, B, C]
```

But when I install the wheel in another client project X, these "source" dependencies are not found (they are not part of A's wheel).

```
Collecting B (from A==0.0.1)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement B (from A==0.0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for B (from A==0.0.1)
```

Do I have to create separate binary distributions for each sub-project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont put `B` and `C` to the `install_requires` list. That is for packages published via the cheese shop (ie pypi). You must put `B` and `C` under `packages` list.

Remember that the dependencies in `install_requires` are not bundled up when you build your python release (binary or not) but packages in `packages` are bundled up with your release (you can view them as just "modules" rather than standalone libraries because that they would be).

To explain this, if you have if you build your wheel and you give it to me and i try to install it, the `nose` package will be fetched from the cheese show and be installed. `B` and `C` will also be attempted to be installed this way but they fail because you never built them and release them to the pypi server.

So you have 2 choices actually. First one is to build `B` and `C` individually and release each of them to the pypi server (or your own pypi server). Another option is to include `B` and `C` as packages on your `setup.py` file. This way, when you build the main project, both `B` and `C` are included in your release (ie the wheel file in your case).

If you choose to build your local dependencies individually and upload them to the pypi server, then your setup should just work. Otherwise if you choose the other option, you have to move local dependencies to packages list. Here is the sample of a setup.py you might create in such a case:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='myproject',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='myself',
    author_email='myself@mywebsite.com',
    install_requires=['nose'],
    packages==['B', 'C']
    package_dir={'A': 'path/to/A/directory', 'B': 'path/to/B/dir'}
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response.  I understand your explanation (I need option 2), but I can't get things to work: I can now build a single wheel, but it the file size looks too small and many modules are missing. My modules B and C each have many subdirectories. 1). Will packages=['B', 'C'] automatically pick these up? 2). How can I inspect the contents of a wheel to check? 3). I'm running "python setup.py bdist_wheel" Is that right? 4. I seem to have to run this from the same directory as set-up.py (E.g., I can't do "python src/main/python/setup.py) otherwise it fails silently.

Comment: OK, so I realize now that I can add multiple find_packages() calls to the packages attribute, so I have things working now. Thanks again.

Comment: @rsb so you have `'B.find_packages()'`? could you provide an example on how to put multiple `find_packages()` calls? and is the bdist_wheel working for you? I've read binary distributions are plataform dependent, is that the case?